# WebAssembly project does not startup with Chrome or IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly

I have been having a problem with debugging a Blazor WebAssembly project. Since im using FireFox it did always launch however, I read that debugging a WASM app is better with chrome so I figured i'd download chrome after doing so i tried starting is up but I got a error saying : "Unable to launch - unkown runtime 'node-x64-lts'". So when I read the note part I thought I might not have Node yet installed that, that did not do the trick either. So I am kinda clueless at this point.[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by reinstalling VS.